# If statement doesn't work properly

Tags: conditional

As the image shows, `If` doesn't return "Fail" if the condition didn't succeed, but works when conditions match. Why did that happen and how can I fix it?

image:
[image]

Comment: try `If[First @ prefix === P, "Correct", "Fail"]`?

Comment: also `If[First@prefix == P, "Correct", "Fail", "Fail"]`?

Comment: You helped me again! Thank you!

Comment: For future purposes it is better to include the code in such a way that it is easy for other members to copy and paste it in a mathematica notebook :-)

Comment: For more (and important) information, `Equal`, `SameQ`, and `PossibleZeroQ` are discussed under "Background and Context" in the docs for `Equal`.  There are also contrasting examples illustrating some of the points shown under "Properties & Relations."

Answer (score 1):

We should use [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`) to force the comparison to evaluate here:

```
If[First @ prefix === P, "Correct", "Fail"]
```